# term_exists not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, if-statement

I finally got my back-end to create the wheel codes from the checked taxonomies in the add custom post admin area.

Now, I want to add that tire code to the wheel_type taxonomy.

The below code ran great, until I added the if statement under //Add code to Taxonomy

Now nothing is working, but I get nothing in the error console.

I figure it must be a stupid syntax mistake - can anyone help me out?

Or am I missing something else?

```
       jQuery('#replace').click(function(){
    //get tire code and name
    var code = jQuery('input[name="tire_code"]').val();
    var name = jQuery('input[name="tire_name"]').val();
    var bname = jQuery('input[name="tire_bname"]').val();

             alert(code + " + " + name + " + " + bname);

    //get tire brand
    var tirebran = jQuery('#tire_brandchecklist').find(":checked").parent('label').text();
    tirebran = jQuery.trim( tirebran );

             //Add code to Taxonomy

             if( term_exists( code, wheel_type ){
         continue;
                  }
        else
         {
                  wp_insert_term( code, wheel_type );
                  }

    //update title
    var title = code + ' : ' + name + ' tires';
    if(tirebran!=''){
        title += ' with ' + bname + ' letters';
    }
    jQuery('input[name="post_title"]').focus().val(title);
});
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless i've misunderstood your question, you're trying to call wordpress methods via javascript.

term_exists() and wp_insert_term() are PHP methods within the wordpress code, not accessible directly via Javascript (unless you have written interfaces to them).

Comment: Ah, I think you are right. So are there javascript equivilants to term_exists() and wp_insert_term(), or do I need to make a function first with them, and call the function from JS? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`continue` doesn't make any sense there; just check for `!term_exists...` and call `wp_insert_term` when it doesn't exist.

```
if (!term_exists(code, wheel_type)) {
    wp_insert_term(code, wheel_type);
}
```

The `continue` statement is for continuing loops from the top of the loop; it does not stand on its own.

Comment: Thanx Dave. I tried it, and got the following Error: term_exists is not defined. It is not liking the !term_exists - but why I don't know. Can you see anything?

Comment: @DaveTras I guess there's no function named "term_exists", is it yours or from another library?